# fallback for the entire typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know we can set optional property using `?` in interface but how to make the entire interface fallback to null or emtpy object?

```
interface MyType {
   abc: string
   def?: number
}
```

I tried

```
interface MyType {
   abc: string
   def?: number
} | {}
```

but now luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd find the easiest way is to not pollute the type more than necessary and have a fallback as e.g.:

```
var MyObject: MyType | {} | undefined;

// Then it can take
MyObject = {};
MyObject = undefined;
MyObject = {abc:"abc"}
MyObject = {abc:"abc", def:1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Partial type

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt

```
interface MyType {
 abc: string
 def?: number
}

const obj: Partial<MyType> = {}
```

Comment: This solves it somewhat, but does so at the price of increased complexity to the type. Also, partial is not a generic solution and would allow for e.g. `{def:1}`, which should not be allowed.